# Use of have/had in this sentence

Tags: tense, verbs

Given these two sentences, talking about a show/concert that has been just experienced:

> 1. I didn't enjoy it as much as I **had** hope to.
> 2. I didn't enjoy it as much as I **have** hope to.

My hunch tells me the only correct option is number one. I am correct in my assumption?

Comment: They're both syntactically invalid. Past Perfect for the lower-level clause: [*I didn't like it as much as I **had hoped***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22didn%27t+like+it+as+much+as+I+had+hoped%22) is the "correct" version (because the hoping happened *before* the failure to enjoy it so much). But you'll sometimes read (and more often, *hear*) Simple Past [*I didn't like it as much as I **hoped.***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22didn%27t+like+it+as+much+as+I+had+hoped%22) It's effectively *optional* whether to include (preposition?) ***to*** at the end. I wouldn't.

Comment: ...actually, thinking of Churchill's [*This is the kind of pedantic nonsense **up with which I will not put***](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/07/04/churchill-preposition/) I'm minded to say ***to*** in this case *isn't* a preposition anyway. It's the ["infinitive marker"](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/infinitive-marker) of ***to enjoy***, without the actual infinitive verb itself: *I didn't like it as much as I had hoped **to enjoy it**.*

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up, @FumbleFingers. Really nice examples too! If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the examples are syntactically invalid. The "correct" version uses Past Perfect for the "lower-level" clause, because the hoping happened before the failure to enjoy it as much as hoped...

> 1: *I didn't enjoy it as much as I **had hoped***

But you'll sometimes read (and more often, *hear*) Simple Past used for the subordinate clause...

> 2: *I didn't enjoy it as much as I **hoped** [to]*

It's effectively optional whether to include ***to*** at the end. Superficially it might look like a preposition, and there's an oft-quoted but rarely observed "pseudo-rule" that you shouldn't end a sentence with a preposition - which Winston Churchill robustly rejected with [*This is the kind of pedantic nonsense **up with which I will not put***](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/07/04/churchill-preposition/). But actually, ***to*** is the "infinitive marker" of ***to enjoy***, where we rarely explicitly repeat the verb itself...

> 3: ?*I didn't enjoy it as much as I had hoped to enjoy it*
> (syntactically valid, but "unusually verbose")